# pagination jquery datatable after delete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable, pagination

After record **delete from datatable**, pagination is not updating.

for refresh datatable I am using this and it is working fine but not refreshing pagination.
$('#mytable').load(location.href + " #mytable")

Answer (score 1):

As Per documentation **row().remove()** method which deletes a row from a table, and the **draw()** method with false as its first parameter. This will redraw the table keeping the current paging (without the false parameter the paging would be reset to the first page).

You can do something like the below no need to refresh it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();// Store your refrence

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );

    $('#removeBtn').click( function () {

     $.ajax({
       url: "deletefile.aspx", 
       success : function(data){
          //delete the row
          table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
        },
       error: function(xhr){
           console.log(xhr);
        }}); 

    } );
} );
```

you can see the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html).

Comment: I AM DOING LIKE THIS FOR DELTE
    $.ajax({
                    url: "ResourceData/Delete",
                    data: { itemIds: ids },
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.status) 
                            $('#myResourceData').dataTable({
                                "paging": false
                            });
                            $("#myResourceData").load(location.href + " #myResourceData");

Comment: why paging false ?

Comment: Now check the code. please share how to reload pagination.
$.ajax({ url: "ResourceData/Delete", data: { itemIds: ids }, type: "POST", cache: false, success: function (response) { if (response.status)  $("#myResourceData").load(location.href + " #myResourceData");

Comment: Basically I want to update info=true  after ajax sucess

Comment: @Bilalkhan have you implemented above code you don't need to updated pagination once table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false ); called it will automatically update the pagination

Comment: Showing 1 to 6 of 6 records 
Basically I want to update this message. how to update this after success call in ajax jquery. when I clear the datatable after success and then reload it, then this message shows like this:
No records found

Comment: @Bilalkhan create a fiddle